# Highcharts Error with Vaadin Charts

Tags: highcharts, vaadin, vaadin-charts

I'm trying to add charts to a Vaadin application (6.8.12) using Vaadin Charts (1.1.2), the later being a wrapper for Highcharts. I have issues compile the project, but at run time the graphs are not portrayed and I get this message in the debug window:

> JavaScriptException: (String): Highcharts error #16:
>   www.highcharts.com/errors/16 Processing time was 140ms for 7645
>   characters of JSON Referenced paintables: 34

I've searched for similar errors but haven't found anything yet. Any hints on what may be going wrong would be helpful.

Thank you.

Comment: For me it means that you are including twice Highcharts/Highstock as said in error.

Comment: The error has a link to the highcharts errors page: http://www.highcharts.com/errors/16

Comment: All the code in the page is generated by Vaadin. How can it be inserting HighCharts twice?